# how to enabled SOAP on PHP 4.3.8

Tags: php, php4

**Current PHP version 4.3.8**

Quick question: just wondering if i can enable the soap file under php.ini. Because currently it throw me this error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: soapclient in /var/www/html/xxx on line 78
```

I think its because the SOAP is disabled, because when i do a phpinfo(), it's not listed as well.

Thanks

Comment: Please update to a current version of PHP. PHP 4.3.8 is eight years old, and is affected by a number of significant security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found just get nusoap and it works fine